# How to interpret hierarchical regression output that has insignificant IV in step 2, but still shows significant F

Tags: r, regression, interpretation, multilevel-analysis

I'm working through a 4-step hierarchical regression where the first step is to add grouping variables (student standing, gender, & previous experience) and the 2nd step as adding a psychological dimension (likert scale relating to psych variables).

On the 2nd step of the regression, the total output/f test is suggesting that model is significant, but the actual addition to the step (i.e., the psych variable) is not (see below for the output). If folks are able, I would love some assistance in understanding this, I'm stumped!

```r
> summary(reg1)

Call:
lm(formula = IASMHS80 ~ Gender + Class + PreviousCounseling, 
    data = mydatareg)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.22725 -0.32881 -0.06004  0.31482  1.39994 

Coefficients:
                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)         2.631108   0.175667  14.978  < 2e-16 ***

Gender             -0.017129   0.061949  -0.277 0.782444  
Class              -0.001098   0.018251  -0.060 0.952099    
PreviousCounseling -0.255314   0.071774  -3.557 0.000468 ***

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.441 on 200 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.06208,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.04801 
F-statistic: 4.413 on 3 and 200 DF,  p-value: 0.004971

> summary(reg2)

Call:
lm(formula = IASMHS80 ~ Gender + Class + PreviousCounseling + 
    IM480, data = mydatareg)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.2229 -0.3121 -0.0627  0.2961  1.4703 

Coefficients:
                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)         2.819675   0.231152  12.198  < 2e-16 ***

Gender             -0.024626   0.062149  -0.396 0.692358   
Class              -0.001788   0.018234  -0.098 0.921988    
PreviousCounseling -0.254564   0.071675  -3.552 0.000478 ***

IM480              -0.037251   0.029738  -1.253 0.211797    

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.4404 on 199 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.06942,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.05072 
F-statistic: 3.711 on 4 and 199 DF,  p-value: 0.006151
```

Answer (score 1):

Your *R*<sup>2</sup> is also really low.  Assuming this is survey data, this means that the respondents' IASMHS80 is not explained well considering their reported gender, class, and previous counseling. You have significance at 99% confidence interval, given that your *p* <  .01. That means that if someone were to survey a sample that represents the same population your study represents, and analyze the results the same way, there is a 99% likelihood that they will find the same results that you have.

As far as what that might look like, the residuals are evenly dispersed around the line of fit, but for the most part, they aren't on the line of fit. Given the coefficients of that regression, you can see that previous counseling is the most evenly dispersed. Whereas the respondents' reported genders and classes are less evenly dispersed.

That being said, I am curious as to how well this data meets the assumptions of multiple linear regression. The residuals' descriptive statistics suggest that there is a likelihood of normal distribution (along with the sample size). How's the variance (homogeneity or homoskedasticity)? How's the independence? Multicollinearity? Outliers?

In the subsequent regression, when you added whatever IM480 represents, The results are extremely similar. You can see that these variables do not explain very much of whatever IASMHS80 is. However, it does suggest that the data consistently doesn't explain this outcome.

Your coefficient of determination (*R*<sup>2</sup>) changed from 0.04801 to 0.05072 for a change of about 0.02%. That means that IM480 explains the outcome an additional 0.02%.